# Range of the sum of two R.V.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let us consider two R.V., $X_1 \backsim Exponential(\lambda=2)$ and $X_2 \backsim uniform$ in $[-1,2]$.
If we take $S= X_1+X_2$, what is its range, where by range I mean the smallest set I s.t. $P(S \in I)=1$ ?
I guess that this is $[-1,\inf)$ because $X_1$ takes only positive values. Does the answer depend on whether $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the answer does depend on independence.  If so, your $[-1,+\infty)$ support for  $X_1+X_2$ is correct

For an alternative, try $X_2 = 3e^{-2X_1} -1$,  which will have a uniform distribution on $[-1,2]$, and where  $X_1+X_2 \ge \log_e(\sqrt{6})-\frac12 \approx 0.3958797$

Comment: Why has $X_2$ in your example a uniform distribution?

Comment: @Alchemy because for a random variable $Z$ with a continuous cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ you can say that the random variable $F(Z)$ has a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Here $X_1$ has cdf $F(x)=1-e^{-2x}$ when $x \ge 0$  and I merely changed the scale and location using $X_2=-3F(X_1)+2$ which keeps it uniform